# Spring MVC: switch between JSON and CSV on the fly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring API that returns JSON using `@ResponseBody`. Is there a way to return either JSON or CSV based on the value of a `RequestParam`, i.e. `&format=json` or `&format=csv`?

Comment: If you already have a CSV message converter, then the client can specify the desired response format by giving the HTTP header `accept` and the desired mime type.

Comment: Check out "Content Negotiation": https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc